# Java JUnit: Test selection of TreeViewer

Tags: java, junit, swt

I wrote a method that returns the selections of a TreeViewer, which I created because I have to get the current selections quite often.

I am trying to test this method with JUnit, but for some reason my manually created selections won't work. Apparently, the Tree in the TreeViewer is not created in the JUnit environment and thus cannot return any selections. 
The debug shows me the following message when I call getItems()
"org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array."

Maybe I am doing entirely wrong, but this is how I am doing it now:

```
TreeNode root = createTestTree();
    viewer.setContentProvider(new TreeNodeContentProvider());
    viewer.setInput(root); //<-- is a tree with at least 9 nodes
    viewer.getTree().update(); //<-- tried to update out of desperation, no effect
    viewer.refresh();

    TreeItem [] items = viewer.getTree().getItems(); //<-- always empty, why
    viewer.getTree().setSelection(items[3]);
    viewer.refresh();
    viewer.getTree().update();

    sel = TreeUtil.getTreeSelections(viewer);
    assertEquals(1, sel.size());
```

How can I create a valid TreeViewer, select something in it for JUnit-Testing?

Comment: Can you show the code for createTestTree? Without seeing it, I would guess that you are not actually adding items to the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that, because your test is ran in UI thread, the viewer could not be refreshed. In this case a solution is to try to let the JVM refresh the view with calling the piece of code after each call of `refresh()` method in your code:

```
    /**
     * Execute pending UI tasks
     */
    public static void doPendingUIJobs() {
        try {
            Thread.yield();
            IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
            if (wb != null) {
                Display display = wb.getDisplay();
                if (display != null) {
                    do {
                    } while (display.readAndDispatch());
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable _) {
            System.out.println("doPendingUIJobs error:" + _);
            _.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```